# Obtaining "KeyError 2" in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

Currently, I am working on a blackjack game within Python. To score  a hand, I call the following function. *highAce*, if true, will score ace's as 11, and if false, will score them as 1.

```
def score_hand(self, highAce):
    curr_score = 0
    special_scores = {'J': 11, 'Q': 12, 'K': 13, 'A': (1, 11)[highAce]}
    for card in self._cards:
        curr_score += special_scores[card[0]] if type(card[0]) is str else card[0]
    return curr_score
```

Everything in `self._cards` is a named-tuple called 'Card' that has a 'rank' and a 'suit'.

The cards are created as follows (this is another class):

```
Card = collections.namedtuple('Card', ['rank', 'suit'])

ranks = [str(n) for n in range(2, 11)] + list('JQKA')
suits = 'spades diamonds clubs hearts'.split()

def __init__(self, seed=None):
 self._cards = [Card(rank, suit) for suit in self.suits for rank in self.ranks]
```

The issue seems to come up in this line 
`curr_score += special_scores[card[0]] if type(card[0]) is str else card[0]`

The iterator takes a look at the 'rank' of each card. If the rank IS NOT a string, that means it is just a number 1~9, which also means we can simply add that to the score. However, if the rank IS A string, that means it is either JQKA. Thus, I either add it's value in the *special_scores* table or its actual rank value.

Comment: JQK are all scored 10 in blackjack.

Answer (score 1):

Your ranks are all strings:

```
>>> ranks = [str(n) for n in range(2, 11)] + list('JQKA')
>>> ranks
['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
```

So `type(card[0]) is str` is always True.  You get a key error because `special_scores` does not have `'2'`, for example, as a key.

A simpler solution is to keep the scores for all strings.  Also only the first ace is counted as 11, so you could do:

```
SCORES = dict(zip('A 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K'.split(),
                  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10]))

def score_hand(cards):
    curr_score = 0
    ace_seen = False
    for card in cards:
        curr_score += SCORES[card.rank]
        if not ace_seen and card.rank == 'A':
            curr_score += 10
            ace_seen = True
    return curr_score
```